# Parceler - unable to find read/write generator for SpannableString

Tags: android, parceler

```
Error:(27, 64) error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type android.text.SpannableString for android.text.SpannableString span2
Error:(27, 87) error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type android.text.SpannableString for android.text.SpannableString span3
Error:(27, 41) error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type android.text.SpannableString for android.text.SpannableString span1
```

I'm getting the above error when I try to build my project. As the classes I'm using are `SpannableString` I know I require some custom serialization which I believe I have implemented. Any ideas?

See my code below:

```
@Parcel
public class ParcelerTest
{
    @ParcelPropertyConverter(SpannableStringParcelConverter.class)
    public SpannableString span1;

    @ParcelPropertyConverter(SpannableStringParcelConverter.class)
    public SpannableString span2;

    @ParcelPropertyConverter(SpannableStringParcelConverter.class)
    public SpannableString span3;

    @ParcelConstructor
    public ParcelerTest(SpannableString span1, SpannableString span2, SpannableString span3)
    {
        this.span1 = span1;
        this.span2 = span2;
        this.span3 = span3;
    }

    public class SpannableStringParcelConverter implements ParcelConverter
    {
        @Override
        public void toParcel(Object input, android.os.Parcel parcel)
        {
            parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(parcel), 0);
        }

        @Override
        public Object fromParcel(android.os.Parcel parcel)
        {
            return Parcels.unwrap(parcel.readBundle(getClass().getClassLoader()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there's a couple problems here, some are legitimate bugs:

1. You need to define your inner class as static.  Parceler should have a better error about this.
2. You need to annotate the constructor parameters.  This is a legitimate bug, you should be able to annotate either.
3. Your ParcelConverter should write and read the contents of SpannableString, Parceler doesn't handle this type directly.  This would cause a runtime error if you tested it.

Here's an updated working version of your code:

```
@Parcel
public class ParcelerTest
{
    public SpannableString span1;
    public SpannableString span2;
    public SpannableString span3;

    @ParcelConstructor
    public ParcelerTest(@ParcelPropertyConverter(SpannableStringParcelConverter.class) SpannableString span1,
                        @ParcelPropertyConverter(SpannableStringParcelConverter.class) SpannableString span2,
                        @ParcelPropertyConverter(SpannableStringParcelConverter.class) SpannableString span3)
    {
        this.span1 = span1;
        this.span2 = span2;
        this.span3 = span3;
    }

    public static class SpannableStringParcelConverter implements ParcelConverter<SpannableString>
    {
        @Override
        public void toParcel(SpannableString input, android.os.Parcel parcel)
        {
            parcel.writeString(input.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public SpannableString fromParcel(android.os.Parcel parcel)
        {
            return new SpannableString(parcel.readString());
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it's a little strange to use a `SpannableString` in the model of your codebase.  Maybe you could just use a plain `String` instead?